# IF statement on MYSQL query - IF all values for a column are the same

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

Is it possible to have a PHP if statement saying if all values of [Column3] are the same, then run some code?

I have a MYSQLi query returning values but if all values for Column 3 are the same, then I want to run another PHP code.

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return one row with one column that is the number of *different* values in `column3`:

```
select count(distinct column3) from mytable
```

If the value is `1`, there's only one value in the column.